# Excesso de redirecionamento no Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Quando eu tento rodar a minha aplicação em codeigniter a página para de carregar e é exibida uma mensagem de erro falando que está havendo um redirecionamento em excesso. Na aplicação, eu preciso estar redirecionando o usuário sempre que não existir uma determinada sessão, e para isso eu estou usando a função redirect()

Qualquer ajuda é bem-vinda, eu agradeço desde já

Prints do erro e da parte do código de redirecionamento: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0ey0.jpg

Comment: Posta o código. Imagem não dá pra copiar e reproduzir. Facilita a vida de quem vai tentar resolver o seu problema.

Comment: Deu Loop nas Views

Answer (score 2):

A sua verificação é feita no seu `/`?

Se sim você está entrando em um *loop* infinito ao redirecionar de volta para `/` caso o usuário não esteja logado.

Em vez de redirecionar para `/`, mande para a página de `/login` ao invés disso e garanta que nessa página não é feita essa verificação e redirecionamento caso o usuário não esteja logado.